# Select the max value from array in mysql query

Tags: mysql

hi i have the following table (battles) :

```
+-----------+------------------------------------------+
| id        | battles                                  |
+-----------+------------------------------------------+
| 1         | 1;2                                      |
| 2         | 231;2                                    |
| 3         | 3330;0                                   |
| 4         | 11;333                                   |
| 5         | 32;3324                                  |
| 7         | 2;1                                      |
| 8         | 333:233                                  |
+-----------+------------------------------------------+
```

The table contains the win and loss of each player (win;lose)

how can i select the biggest win (3330;0)

Comment: What defines the "biggest win"?

Comment: The table battles contains values as follows (win;lose)

Comment: But is the biggest win the highest `win` value or the highest `win-lose` value?

Comment: I have to split battles to win / lose then I chose the highest win

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last entry must be

> | 7         | 333;233

to work properly. i believe it is only a typo

```
SELECT id,battles, maximal
From battles t inner join
(Select 
MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(battles,';',1)+0) maximal
FRom battles) t1 on t1.maximal = SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.battles,';',1);
```

The result is

```
d   battles     maximal
3   3330;0      3330
```

If you had more ids with 3300 then they would also appear in the result

Comment: hi thanks but what is that for (maximal)

Comment: something wrong with the query

Comment: maximal is the biggest win in your battles column which you defined as win;lose so that id number 3 has 3300 wins and 0 losses.

Comment: the query did not work

Comment: Of course it does see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e19e8c/1

Comment: It gives me 9 when the highest win is 500 (I have more than 1,700 values in the table)

Comment: I wrote in my answer that with my query you get every id that has the highest win. so specify another characteristic to minimize or Limit 1 at the end so that it returns only 1.

Comment: @alex555 _"It gives me 9 when the highest win is 500"_ is because the query treated value as string. You can try using cast in the subquery like for example `MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(battles,';',1) AS INT))`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thanks